# Defining perpendicular lines in the 3D space

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, convention

Is there a universal agreement about the definition of "perpendicularity" between two stright lines in the 3 dimensional euclidean space? Do they need to meet or it is enough to have perpendicular *directions*? Do you know any reference that could settle the issue?

Comment: What is the context in which you are considering perpendicular lines?

Comment: It could be synthetic geometry or analytic geometry of the space

Comment: Two straight lines in three dimensional space (the usual, Euclidean one) are perpendicular if and only if the intersect *and*  the dot product (inner product) of their direction vectors is zero.

Comment: @Joanpemo do you have a reference?

Comment: @Brody "Preferable"? I think that otherwise the direction vectors won't be perpendicular.

Comment: @MarcoDisce Read here from page 7 and on: http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/10-fall/mth234/w3-234-h.pdf

Comment: @Joanpemo your link provide a definition that is different from yours and it says also "Perpendicular lines in space may not intersect" (page 7)

Comment: @MarcoDisce Fine, so that's a different definition. Choose the one that fits better what you want or what your notes require. Or maybe this answers your question "is there a universal...". NO, there is not. See for example the first seconds of https://www.brightstorm.com/math/precalculus/vectors-and-parametric-equations/perpendicular-parallel-and-skew-lines-in-space/

Comment: @Joanpemo thanks for the links

Comment: @Brody Thank you. yet in your example the lines don't even intersect. If "they" did, say for example with $\;r_2(t)=tj\;,\;\;or\;\;r_2(t)=tj+tk\;$ , then they're perpendicular at their interesection point $\;(0,0,0)\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo I believe I misunderstood your initial reply, as I thought "at a point of intersection" was the topic of disagreement. My apologies. I'll delete my comments as to "declutter" the post.

Comment: @Brody Thank you. No need to delete as these comments sometimes give nice insights to other.